# Drawing BufferedImage to JFrame causes NullPointerException Even when the image and graphics are initialized

Tags: java, game-engine

So I'm writing a 2d game engine, and right now, I'm trying to get a simple `Chunk` to render, but when I do, I get a blank window, and the following comes up on my console:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at sfortress.graphics.image.TileIcon.<init>(TileIcon.java:31)
at sfortress.game.tile.Tiles.init(Tiles.java:15)
at sfortress.SFortress.init(SFortress.java:28)
at sfortress.SFortress.main(SFortress.java:31)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at sfortress.graphics.image.TileIcon.<init>(TileIcon.java:31)
at sfortress.game.tile.Tiles.init(Tiles.java:21)
at sfortress.SFortress.init(SFortress.java:28)
at sfortress.SFortress.main(SFortress.java:31)
TILES: 2
Initializing 16x16 Chunk...     [ DONE ]
Generating Chunk...      [ OKAY ]
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at sfortress.graphics.image.TileIcon.<init>(TileIcon.java:31)
at sfortress.SFortress.run0(SFortress.java:39)
at sfortress.game.tile.Tiles.init(Tiles.java:28)
at sfortress.SFortress.init(SFortress.java:28)
at sfortress.SFortress.main(SFortress.java:31)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at japi.window.panel.ImagePanel.paintComponent(ImagePanel.java:55)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at japi.window.panel.ImagePanel.paintComponent(ImagePanel.java:55)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at japi.window.panel.ImagePanel.paintComponent(ImagePanel.java:55)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've re-written my code 8 or 9 (I lost count) times in the last week and a half, but I've only been able to render anything by calling `ImageIO.read(File file)` directly in the draw method (which would be very inefficient once I actually get the engine working) If anyone knows how to solve this, I would REALLY appreciate it. All involved code below:

## SFortress.java

```
package sfortress;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

import util.OS;

import japi.window.panel.ImagePanel;

import sfortress.*;
import sfortress.game.*;
import sfortress.game.character.*;
import sfortress.game.data.positioning.*;
import sfortress.game.tile.*;
import sfortress.graphics.image.TileIcon;
import sfortress.world.chunk.*;

public class SFortress {
  public static String sPath;

  public static void init() {
    sPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    OS.init();
    Game.init();
    Tiles.init();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
  }
  public static void run0() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel();
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(16,new Position("chunk",0,0,0)).generate();
    BufferedImage image = null;
    image = chunk.draw();
    panel.setImage(image);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(512,512);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Chunk Rendering Test v5");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static String path(String input) {
    return ("." + sPath + "." + input).replace("..",".").replace('.',OS.dirChar);
  }
}
```

## Chunk.java

```
package sfortress.world.chunk;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import sfortress.game.Game;
import sfortress.game.data.positioning.*;
import sfortress.world.chunk.TileSlot;

import static sfortress.game.Game.world;

public class Chunk {
  public TileSlot[][][] slots;
  public int scale;
  public Position loc;

  public Chunk(int scale,Position loc) {
    System.out.print("Initializing " + scale + 'x' + scale + " Chunk...");
    this.scale = scale;
    this.loc = loc;
    this.slots = new TileSlot[scale][scale][scale];
    for (int x = 0; x < scale; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < scale; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < scale; z++) {
          slots[x][y][z] = new TileSlot();
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("     [ DONE ]");
  }

  /*public void load() {
    new ChunkFile(Game.world.getPath(".chunks.c-x"+loc.x+"_y"+loc.y+"_z"+loc.z+".chunk"),this).load();
  }
  public void unLoad() {
    new ChunkFile(Game.world.getPath(".chunks.c-x"+loc.x+"_y"+loc.y+"_z"+loc.z+".chunk"),this).save();
  }*/

  private Position pgd(int x, int y, int z, Side side) {
    Position pk = null;
    if (side == Side.TOP) {
      pk = new Position("tile",y,x,z);
    } else if (side == Side.BOTTOM) {
      pk = new Position("tile",-y,x,z);
    } else if (side == Side.LEFT) {
      pk = new Position("tile",z,-y,-x);
    } else if (side == Side.RIGHT) {
      pk = new Position("tile",z,y,x);
    } else if (side == Side.FRONT) {
      pk = new Position("tile",z,x,-y);
    } else if (side == Side.BACK) {
      pk = new Position("tile",z,-x,y);
    }
    return pk;
  }
  public BufferedImage draw() {
    Side side = Game.viewerSide;
    Position pos = Game.viewerPosition;
    Position kloc = loc.convert("pixel");
    int px = Game.spriteScale * scale;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(px,px,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
    for (int x = 0; x < scale; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < scale; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < scale; z++) {
          Position p = pgd(x,y,z,side);
          g.drawImage(slots[p.x][p.y][p.z].getTile().draw(side)[0],0,0,null);
        }
      }
    }
    g.dispose();
    return image;
  }

  public Chunk generate() {
    System.out.print("Generating Chunk...");
    for (int x = 0; x < scale; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < scale; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < scale; z++) {
          slots[x][y][z].setTile(sfortress.game.tile.Tiles.rand());
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("      [ OKAY ]");
    return this;
  }
}
```

## Game.java

```
package sfortress.game;

import sfortress.game.data.positioning.*;
import sfortress.world.World;

public final class Game {
  public static World world;
  public static int spriteScale;
  public static Position viewerPosition;
  public static Side viewerSide;

  public static void init() {
    spriteScale = 16;
    viewerPosition = new Position("pixel",127,127,255);
    viewerSide = Side.TOP;
    world = new World("Unnamed",12,16);
  }
}
```

## TileIcon.java

```
package sfortress.graphics.image;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import sfortress.SFortress;
import sfortress.game.data.positioning.*;
import sfortress.graphics.image.GImage;

public class TileIcon extends GImage {
  private BufferedImage top;
  private BufferedImage bottom;
  private BufferedImage right;
  private BufferedImage left;
  private BufferedImage front;
  private BufferedImage back;

  public float glow;

  public TileIcon() {}
  public TileIcon(String name) {
    String p = SFortress.path(".data.sprites.name.");
    File fTop = new File(p + "top.png");
    File fBot = new File(p + "bottom.png");
    File fRig = new File(p + "right.png");
    File fLef = new File(p + "left.png");
    File fFro = new File(p + "front.png");
    File fBac = new File(p + "back.png");
    try {
      front = ImageIO.read(fFro);
      back = ImageIO.read(fBac);
      left = ImageIO.read(fLef);
      right = ImageIO.read(fRig);
      top = ImageIO.read(fTop);
      bottom = ImageIO.read(fBot);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void tick() {}
  public BufferedImage[] draw(Side side) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    switch (side.toString().toLowerCase()) {
      case "bottom":
        image = bottom;
        break;
      case "right":
        image = right;
        break;
      case "left":
        image = left;
        break;
      case "front":
        image = front;
        break;
      case "back":
        image = back;
        break;
      default:
        image = top;
        break;
    }
    return new BufferedImage[] {image,sfortress.graphics.Renderer.makeGlowLayer(image)};
  }
}
```

## Tiles.java

```
package sfortress.game.tile;

import java.util.*;

import sfortress.game.tile.*;
import sfortress.graphics.image.TileIcon;

public class Tiles {
  public static ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

  public static void init() {
    SolidTile stone = new SolidTile();
    stone.name = "Stone";
    stone.id = "tiles.stone";
    stone.icon = new TileIcon("tiles.stone");
    stone.meltingPoint = 3000f;
    stone.fluidForm = null;
    SolidTile sandstone = new SolidTile();
    sandstone.name = "Sandstone";
    sandstone.id = "tiles.sandstone";
    sandstone.icon = new TileIcon("tiles.sandstone");
    sandstone.meltingPoint = 3000f;
    sandstone.fluidForm = null;
    tiles.add(stone);
    tiles.add(sandstone);
    System.out.println("TILES: " + tiles.size());

    sfortress.SFortress.run0();
  }

  public static Tile rand() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(tiles.size()-1);
    return tiles.get(index);
  }
}
```

## VoidIcon.java

```
package sfortress.graphics.image;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import sfortress.game.Game;

public class VoidIcon extends TileIcon {
  public void tick() {
    return;
  }
  public BufferedImage[] draw() {
    return new BufferedImage[] {new BufferedImage(Game.spriteScale,Game.spriteScale,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB),null};
  }
}
```

## GImage.java

```
package sfortress.graphics.image;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import sfortress.game.data.positioning.*;

public abstract class GImage {
  public float glow;

  public abstract void tick();
  public abstract BufferedImage[] draw(Side side);
}
```

## Tile.java

```
package sfortress.game.tile;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import sfortress.game.data.positioning.*;
import sfortress.graphics.image.TileIcon;
import sfortress.world.chunk.TileSlot;

public abstract class Tile {
  public String name;
  public String id;
  public TileIcon icon;
  public float density;

  protected TileSlot slot;

  public abstract Tile fabricate();

  public void tick() {
    icon.tick();
  }
  public void destroy() {
    return;
  }
  public BufferedImage[] draw(Side side) {
    return icon.draw(side);
  }
  public void set(TileSlot slot) {
    this.slot = slot;
  }
}
```

## ImagePanel.java

```
package japi.window.panel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
  private BufferedImage image;

  public ImagePanel() {
  }
  public ImagePanel(String path) {
    try {
      setImage(ImageIO.read(new File(path)));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public ImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
    setImage(image);
  }

  public void setImage(String image) {
    try {
      this.image = ImageIO.read(new File(image));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    repaint();
  }
  public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public int getWidth() {
    return 512;
  }

  @Override
  public int getHeight() {
    return 512;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

Also, please tell me If I'm missing a file that you think might help to solve this (I have 36 files in total).

Comment: Based on the stack trace, one of your images isn't been loaded because it's an unrecognised format

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll check that out.

Comment: alright, considering that all the images loaded in Windows Photo Viewer, I'd say they're not corrupted (I checked all 10). Thanks for the tip though

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what SFortress.path(".data.sprites.name.") returns

Comment: It's for cross-platform compatibility. I give it something like `".data.sprites.lava"` and if I'm in Windows, it gives me `"\\data\\sprites\\lava"`. Then I can just add `".png"` to the output

Comment: also. I put ".name" in a moment of idiocy (or a long period of idiocy I guess) as that was supposed to be `".data.sprites." + name + "."`. That was actually the problem, it turns out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problems are caused by stuff like this:

```
try {
  image = chunk.draw();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You are catching exceptions and then ... basically ... ignoring them.  It is called *exception squashing* and it is a bad idea.

In this particular case, when the exception is squashed, you won't assign anything to `image`.  If `image` was `null` to start with, it will remain `null`.  If your code then tries to use it (without checking for `null`) then an NPE is the most likely outcome.

---

> If anyone knows how to solve this, I would REALLY appreciate it.

Solution:

1. Get rid of all cases of exception squashing in your code.  If you can't handle the checked exceptions, let them propagate ... and crash the application.
2. Once your application is crashing due to the unexpected exceptions, find what causes them, and fix that.

---

In this case, it looks like you have a problem with image loading.  A comment suggests that it might be that you are using an image format that Java does not understand.

You commented:

> alright, considering that all the images loaded in Windows Photo Viewer, I'd say they're not corrupted

That's beside the point.  The suggestion was that the images are in the wrong format, not that they are corrupted.

---

After a bit more digging, here is the library code that throws the initial exception with that message:

```
public static BufferedImage  read(File input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
    }
    if (!input.canRead()) {
        throw new IIOException("Can't read input file!");
    }
    ....
}
```

This means that the problem is that either the pathname that your application is using for the image file is wrong (i.e. it cannot be resolved), or there is a file or directory permission problem.  Note that at this point the image reader has not attempted to read the file.  It is just applying some tests prior to attempting to open it.

(And based on your final comments, this *was* the problem.)

Comment: The "try-catch" block is there because at one point I had used an ImageIO.read statement to see if I was going crazy. I wasn't, It worked. Forgot to remove that when I pasted the code. I'll edit it

Comment: @OP You're doing the same thing in the TileIcon constructor, as the stack trace shows: the file can't be read, but you ignore the exception, leaving one or several images null, and then trying to draw them as if nothing bad happened while initializing them. Don't ignore exceptions. Add them to the throws clause if you can't handle them properly, and let them bubble up the stack. Or at least, if you catch them, throw a runtime exception wrapping them.

Comment: Adding try-catch blocks because you are going crazy means you will go crazy later on.  But 10 times worse crazy.  Just don't do it.

Comment: If the problem was in reading the file, would have fixed it already (as I have several times already). I can get the file to load, and display when I tell it to load directly in the `draw` function, but not when referencing a BufferedImage variable. If you're not going to help, please don't respond.

Comment: Sorry mate ... but if you think our advice is not intended to help you, then you clearly don't understand it.  Please re-read it.

Comment: *If the problem was in reading the file*: You **do have** a problem reading the file. Otherwise, you wouldn't have a stack trace saying: *javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)*. Just read the error message instead of, once again, ignoring it.

Comment: You clearly didn't understand my comment. Please re-read it! I didn't add the try-catch statement because I was crazy, I added the `ImageIO.read` statement because I was crazy. I added the try-catch because you need to catch or throw an `IOException` to call `ImageIO.read`

Comment: And you chose the bad choice: catching the exception and ignoring it. Choose the other solution: add the exception to the throws clause of your method. That's the whole point of Stephen's answer. Read it.

Comment: Found the issue. Sorry for my slowness, I've been trying to get this thing working since Feb 17

Comment: And another piece of free advice: responding with "If you're not going to help, please don't respond." to people who are >>clearly<< trying to help you is >>not<< a good idea.  If you want help, then be civil.

Comment: Also, about the "unrecognised file format comment", I know that that isn't the case, because I've loaded these images by themselves before, just not through the TileIcon class

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I put ".sprites.name" instead of ".sprites." + name

Comment: Thank you though.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry for my arrogance and rudeness. I was really tired, and had been working on that project for a long time. Additionally, I didn't know how to properly format my question (even though the site LITERALLY TOLD ME how to do it)! In short, I was (and still am) an idiot, and I apologize.